# Is it possible to track actual affiliate sales in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, affiliate, affiliates

I have a website that I built and am getting sales everyday now via "affiliate window" I was curious if it was possible to track the commission in analytics so I am able to see what pages are performing the best?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should look into purpose-built affiliate trackers. Voluum, Thrive, Adsbridge etc. CharlesNgo.com has a lot of info about these.

You can also use these trackers to dynamically insert user data into your landing pages, and they are a lot easier than GA to use. Example: https://charlesngo.com/how-to-insert-user-data-into-landing-pages-using-voluum-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

After a clarifying comment: Yes, you can do this, although with some caveats (one of them that it might not be worth the effort unless you make a lot from your affiliate pages).

You can do data imports, and more specifically you can add data to urls (there are different kinds of data import and "content data" is one of them).

You need a dataset that contains a "key" field that is used to match external data to GA data and one or more fields with values you want to import.

Imported data is always dimensions, i.e. categorical data ([that is per Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6066726) The interface allow to to select custom metrics, but I have not yet tried this and cannot give any guidance on how that would work). So if you try to import revenue you have the problem that new entries will not be added to existing entries, they will replace them

What I would probably do is to sort the data from the "affiliate window" into three categories (low, medium, high), and then prepare a csv file with the urls as first column and the categories as second column.

Then create a custom dimension with a name of i.e. "performance" (else you'd have to overwrite an existing dimension in GA and you probably not want that).

Both custom dimensions and data imports are created on a property level (however you can apply an import to a specific view and I would urge you to test this on a test view first). So in the property settings go to data import, new, content data. Key will be "page", Imported data will be the custom dimension you just created. Check "overwrite hit data" (else the data will not change after the first import, however note that this might make comparisons between different timeframes difficult).

Download the "schema" file (simply a template for your csv upload file in which you insert your data). Click finish.

Next go to data imports, "manage uploads" and upload the file. Processing will take a day or so (errors, if any, you will see shortly after the upload).

Then go to your content reports, select your custom  dimension as secondary dimension and you will if the url in question was a low, medium or high performer.

You can automate this via the GA API, bit that's a bit beyond an SO answer.

---- (old answer)--- 
This is actually what [campaign parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en) are for. Your affiliate links should be tagged with campaign parameters, e.g.

> http://example.com/?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=[[Affliate
>   Name]]&utm_campaign=[[Campaign Name]]

The things in the angled brackets are placeholders, you would replace those with the name of your affiliate and the name of your campaign.

Now you can look into the aquisition reports and group by source (values for all affiliate links), by source (breakdown by affiliate name) or campaigns, or combinations thereof.

However tracking the commission you pay out via Google Analytics is probably not a good idea, at least from the point of view of your affiliates - JavaScript based tracking is not necessarily accurate enough to track billable services (some people have js disabled or opted out of GA or use adblockers that block tracking etc).

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent on your response. I don't think I explained well enough so my apologies. My website is an affiliate site, I currently have affiliate links on my website that links users to the product page. I was curious if it was possible to pull information from Affiliate Window into my GA so I can see how much commission I am getting from certain pages etc. Is this possible?

Comment: @BubblewrapBeast, amended my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You can use sub-id's and fill them with unique visitor data (Google Analytics Used ID). Once an affiliate sale is tracked in an affiliate network, you'll get the sub-id that generated the sale. You can now push that sale to google analytics and let google analytics match the visitor data with their data, showing you the full visitor reports (including landingpage info etc.). You need developer skills to get this working with your affiliate networks but there are complete easy to use tools that does the trick for you such as [Ivanhoe.io](https://ivanhoe.io) and Coincrack.